# How to add product to cart in WooCommerce using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Is it possible to add a product to cart with a new price using JavaScript? I have been working on a little script that calculates the price of the product. I would really like to write a function like this:

```
function addToCart(productID, productPrice) {
    //add the product to cart with JavaScript
}
```

Any help or pointers would be deeply appreciated.

So far I have written 4 main files:

- functions.js - calculates and shows the current price based on options the customer chooses (this works fine)
- ajaxSubmit.js - jQuery ajax to send the variables to my PHP files (sends successfully)
- post.php - file where the variables are sent
- simple.php - the single product PHP file which displays the product

I have been able to send the variable from the JavaScript function to my product but I don't know how to add the product to cart.

My post.php looks like this:

**EDIT: The following code works now and adds the product with the id 747**

```
<?php

require('../../../../../../wp-load.php');
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(747);

sleep(3);

if (empty($_POST['ammount'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You didnt select the amount.';
}

else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $final_amount = $_POST['ammount'] * 10;
    $return['msg'] = 'Youve chosen: ' . $final_amount . '.';
}

echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

I have found out that you can add a product into the cart using the following code in PHP:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
```

Then I tried adding these 2 lines into my post.php and it didn't work and also the form stopped working. If I add this into my simple.php (which basically displays the product) it works fine.

My question is: How can I add a product into the cart using this setup?

Comment: If I need to post the code from other files to better understand my problem, please say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a product using AJAX I had to include the wp-load.php into my post.php file. That way I could access to the woocommerce variable and later add the product. Look above for the code fix.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
require('../../../../../../wp-load.php');
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
```

need to take care of the correct path of "wp-load.php"